# La barra inferior (tab bar) desaparece de la vista en el app

Tags: html, framework7

Estoy haciendo una app híbrida con Framework7, la quiero hacer con una [tab bar](https://framework7.io/docs/tabbar.html) que estará abajo. Funciona todo perfectamente siempre y cuando en las páginas de la tab bar yo no haya escrito ni texto ni código, pero si escribo o añado cualquier cosa la navbar se desplaza hasta más abajo del límite de la app  (Que tienes que hacer scroll hacia abajo para verla) y ya no puedes dar click en la tab bar para que lleve a sus respectivas páginas.

Éste es el código de la tab bar:

```
<div class="toolbar tabbar tabbar-labels">
  <div class="toolbar-inner">
    <a href="#tab1" class="tab-link active">
      <i class="icon demo-icon-1"></i>
      <span class="tabbar-label">Label 1</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#tab2" class="tab-link">
      <i class="icon demo-icon-2">
        <span class="badge bg-red">5</span>
      </i>
      <span class="tabbar-label">Label 2</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#tab3" class="tab-link">
      <i class="icon demo-icon-3"></i>
      <span class="tabbar-label">Label 3</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#tab4" class="tab-link">
      <i class="icon demo-icon-4"></i>
      <span class="tabbar-label">Label 4</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y éste es el código de la primera página con lo que yo he incluido (Un item list y algo de texto), y para que la tab bar se vea y funcione tengo que quitar el texto y la item list.

```
<div data-page="index-1" class="page">
  <!-- Scrollable page content-->
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-block-title"><center><font size="3">Download Apps!<font size="3"></center></div>
    <div class="content-block">
      <font size= "3">
        <p><center>Here's where you can download any app/tweak you want!</center></p>
        <div class="content-block-title"><center>Categories:</center></div>
        <div class="list-block media-list inset">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
                <div class="item-media"><img src="..." width="44"></div>
                <div class="item-inner">
                  <div class="item-title-row">
                    <div class="item-title">Hacked apps</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-subtitle">Prehacked apps with unlimited gold/gems/coins (Specified at app installation page!)</div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            ...
          </ul>
        </div>          
        <font size= "3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

He probado haciendo todo tipo de cosas: quitando solo parte del código, etc. pero para que funcione hay que quitarlo todo y no se puede dejar nada.

PD: Le pasé los archivos a un amigo y me dijo que no sabía, pero me lo subió a un servidor gratuito para que lo pudierais ver a ver si me podíais ayudar: https://goo.gl/oRvMRt

Answer (score 0):

> NOTA: No he usado nunca Framework7 y no lo tengo instalado, por lo que puede que el código de abajo no funcione (no he podido probarlo), mi respuesta se basa en la documentación oficial encontrada online.

Si entiendo bien, el problema real es que el tab bar debería estar fijo (*fixed*) y no lo está, el contenido lo empuja hacia abajo de la página. Realmente es un problema con el posicionamiento. Ahora, si vas a la [documentación de Framework7 para los tab bar](https://framework7.io/docs/tabbar.html) verás que hay una nota (traducción mía):

> Por su altura, deberías usar "tabbar-labels-fixed" o "tabbar-labels-through" para [diseño Fixed y Through](https://framework7.io/docs/navbar-toolbar-layouts.html) con Tab Bar

Y si visitas la página enlazada, y vas a la sección para el [diseño fijo (Fixed)](https://framework7.io/docs/navbar-toolbar-layouts.html#fixed-layout), verás que se especifica que (de nuevo traducción mía):

> En un diseño fijo cada página tiene su propio navbar y toolbar que siempre estará visible en la pantalla, y no depende del scroll de la página

que es exactamente lo que estás buscando (de nuevo, si he entendido bien). Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es añadir la clase "tabbar-labels-fixed" o "toolbar-fixed" en tu código. En la última página enlazada tiene un ejemplo usando "tollbar-fixed" y (aplicado a tu código) sería algo como esto:

```
<div data-page="index-1" class="page toolbar-fixed">
  <!-- Scrollable page content-->
  <div class="page-content">
```

Aparte de eso, el código de la página que compartes es incorrecto (hay etiquetas que se abren pero no se cierran), no sé si eso podría influir en que se vea mal, pero sí sería bueno que lo corrigieses de todos modos.